# Blazor WebAssembly with AzureAD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, azure-active-directory, blazor-client-side

I need to let the user of the WebAssembly app I'm developing to login through AzureAD.
I'm using the repo [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web.git) (and UI).

Here what I did so far:

appsetting.json

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Domain": "xxx",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",

    "ClientSecret": "xxx"
  },
```

Server side startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        //services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddSignIn("AzureAD", Configuration, options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));

        // Looks like I need this to have the login UI
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBlazorDebugging();
        }

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Program>();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Program>("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

UserController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public AppUser Get()
    {
        AppUser toReturn = new AppUser();
        if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            toReturn.UserName = this.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            toReturn.UserName = ""; // Not logged in
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Client program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

        // Use our CustomAuthenticationProvider as the 
        // AuthenticationStateProvider
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationProvider>();

        // Add Authentication support
        builder.Services.AddOptions();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal user;

        // Call the GetUser method to get the status
        // This only sets things like the AuthorizeView
        // and the AuthenticationState CascadingParameter
        var result = await _httpClient.GetJsonAsync<AppUser>("api/user");

        // Was a UserName returned?
        if (result.UserName != "")
        {
            // Create a ClaimsPrincipal for the user
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result.UserName),
            }, "AzureAdAuth");
            user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            user = new ClaimsPrincipal(); // Not logged in
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }
}
```

App.razor

```html
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Login.razor

```html
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h6>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name! </h6>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">[Log out]</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">[Log in]</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I can login if I manually enter the route https://localhost:xxxxx/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn. And when the user is logged in, everything works as expected.

I have the following exception when the user is not logged in, and blazor try to load the `<AuthorizeView />` part of the layout:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44316%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%xxx%2Fuser_impersonation&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxx&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44316/api/user') from origin 'https://localhost:44316' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I'm trying to enable CORS on the server side as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but I had no success yet.
What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like your API is redirecting your API calls to AAD. You should implement authentication in your front-end with MSAL. And your API needs to support JWTs as well as interactive authentication.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, I should move the authentication to AAD from the server side to the client side on Blazor with MSAL?

Comment: Yes, that's the typical approach with JS front-ends :) Blazor isn't different in that regard, it's a rich front-end app

Comment: That makes sense, I got confused by this: http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4370/Client-Side-Blazor-Authentication-Using-Azure-AD-and-a-Custom-AuthenticationStateProvider.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/

The preview 2 of Blazor WebAssembly comes with a working template out of the box.